# Splitting a string without ignoring spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to find a way to split a String in Java without ignoring the spaces. 
After searching I've found a way to do it in python :

```
re.split(r"(\s+)", "This is the string I want to split")
```

would result in:

```
['This', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'string', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'want', ' ', 'to', ' ', 'split']
```

How can this be done in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you need to use lookarounds.

```
string.split("(?<=\\s+)|(?=\\s+)");
```

- `(?<=\\s+)` Matches the boundary which exists after one or more spaces.
- `|` OR
- `(?=\\s+)` Matches the boundary which exits before one or more spaces.
- Splitting according to the matched boundary will give you the desired output.

**Example:**

```
String s = "This is the string I want to split";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=\\s+)|(?=\\s+)"); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

**Output:**

```
[This,  , is,  , the,  , string,  , I,  , want,  , to,  , split]
```